# Github overwrote updated files from a previous commit without being able to retrieve the updated files?

Tags: github, restore, github-for-mac

I had made some changes to the code and wanted to create a new branch to reflect those changes.
Using the github software on mac, Peak Meme (162), I clicked on branches, clicked the + sign next to master, created a branch called updating-design. I think I clicked publish.
Then I went into PHP storm and all the code from the last few days was deleted.
The code was deleted from my local clone. I was trying to push the changes I had made through the new branch.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the git reflog and retrieve it from the command line

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you were already working on another branch without realizing it, and now you've checked out a new branch that doesn't have the work.  Double-check your list of branches.

Git is pretty adamant about not deleting your work just because you switched branches.